# Copying a portion of .docx file (keep formatting and images)

Tags: python, python-docx

Good day SO,

I am trying to copy a part of a .docx file into another .docx file, while keeping the formatting of the copied part, as well as any images, using python.

I have tried python-docx but i am unable to find anything regarding images. Link to my previous qn here: [Extracting .docx data, images and structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57554398/python-extracting-docx-data-images-and-structure)

Is there a way for me to copy a part of a document, lets say DocA, and insert it into the ending of DocB (Including images and formatting, basically a clean copy and paste situation)?

Thanks alot!

EDIT:
I have managed to find paragraphs containing images in DocA using the following code. I understand that it is a very hack-ish way as I am a complete beginner in python-docx, but here it is:

```
for x in document.paragraphs:
    if "<w:pict" in x._p.xml:
        print(x._p.xml)
```

Using this code, I successfully managed to find paragraphs containing the said images in the document. However, I am still unable to copy the image over to DocB (It appears as blanks in DocB), which is because (based on my understanding) I didn't extract the image data from the .docx file DocA.

EDIT 2:

Here is the XML of the Paragraph object containing the images:

```
<w:p xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" w14:paraId="18A83B04" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00200C54" w:rsidRDefault="00051C61" w:rsidP="00200C54">
  <w:pPr>
    <w:jc w:val="center"/>
  </w:pPr>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:pict w14:anchorId="30C19523">
      <v:shapetype id="_x0000_t202" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="202" path="m,l,21600r21600,l21600,xe">
        <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
        <v:path gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
      </v:shapetype>
      <v:shape id="Text Box 2" o:spid="_x0000_s1029" type="#_x0000_t202" style="position:absolute;left:0;text-align:left;margin-left:305.1pt;margin-top:112.75pt;width:86.25pt;height:19.5pt;z-index:1;visibility:visible;mso-wrap-distance-top:3.6pt;mso-wrap-distance-bottom:3.6pt;mso-width-relative:margin;mso-height-relative:margin" o:gfxdata="UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbJSRQU7DMBBF&#10;90jcwfIWJU67QAgl6YK0S0CoHGBkTxKLZGx5TGhvj5O2G0SRWNoz/78nu9wcxkFMGNg6quQqL6RA&#10;0s5Y6ir5vt9lD1JwBDIwOMJKHpHlpr69KfdHjyxSmriSfYz+USnWPY7AufNIadK6MEJMx9ApD/oD&#10;OlTrorhX2lFEilmcO2RdNtjC5xDF9pCuTyYBB5bi6bQ4syoJ3g9WQ0ymaiLzg5KdCXlKLjvcW893&#10;SUOqXwnz5DrgnHtJTxOsQfEKIT7DmDSUCaxw7Rqn8787ZsmRM9e2VmPeBN4uqYvTtW7jvijg9N/y&#10;JsXecLq0q+WD6m8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJl&#10;bHOkkMFqwzAMhu+DvYPRfXGawxijTi+j0GvpHsDYimMaW0Yy2fr2M4PBMnrbUb/Q94l/f/hMi1qR&#10;JVI2sOt6UJgd+ZiDgffL8ekFlFSbvV0oo4EbChzGx4f9GRdb25HMsYhqlCwG5lrLq9biZkxWOiqY&#10;22YiTra2kYMu1l1tQD30/bPm3wwYN0x18gb45AdQl1tp5j/sFB2T0FQ7R0nTNEV3j6o9feQzro1i&#10;OWA14Fm+Q8a1a8+Bvu/d/dMb2JY5uiPbhG/ktn4cqGU/er3pcvwCAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAA&#10;IQBxa2hSIQIAAB0EAAAOAAAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWysU11v2yAUfZ+0/4B4X+x4cdNYcaouXaZJ&#10;3YfU7gdgjGM04DIgsbtfvwtO06h7m+YHxPW9HM4997C+GbUiR+G8BFPT+SynRBgOrTT7mv543L27&#10;psQHZlqmwIiaPglPbzZv36wHW4kCelCtcARBjK8GW9M+BFtlmee90MzPwAqDyQ6cZgFDt89axwZE&#10;1yor8vwqG8C11gEX3uPfuylJNwm/6wQP37rOi0BUTZFbSKtLaxPXbLNm1d4x20t+osH+gYVm0uCl&#10;Z6g7Fhg5OPkXlJbcgYcuzDjoDLpOcpF6wG7m+atuHnpmReoFxfH2LJP/f7D86/G7I7KtaTFfUmKY&#10;xiE9ijGQDzCSIuozWF9h2YPFwjDib5xz6tXbe+A/PTGw7ZnZi1vnYOgFa5HfPJ7MLo5OOD6CNMMX&#10;aPEadgiQgMbO6SgeykEQHef0dJ5NpMLjlfmqfL8sKeGYKxbLqzINL2PV82nrfPgkQJO4qanD2Sd0&#10;drz3IbJh1XNJvMyDku1OKpUCt2+2ypEjQ5/s0pcaeFWmDBlquiqLMiEbiOeThbQM6GMldU2v8/hN&#10;zopqfDRtKglMqmmPTJQ5yRMVmbQJYzNiYdSsgfYJhXIw+RXfF256cL8pGdCrNfW/DswJStRng2Kv&#10;5otFNHcKFuWywMBdZprLDDMcoWoaKJm225AeRNTBwC0OpZNJrxcmJ67owSTj6b1Ek1/GqerlVW/+&#10;AAAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAiK7BRuMAAAAQAQAADwAAAGRycy9kb3ducmV2LnhtbExPy26D&#10;MBC8V+o/WFupl6oxQQESgon6UKtek+YDDN4ACl4j7ATy992e2stKuzM7j2I3215ccfSdIwXLRQQC&#10;qXamo0bB8fvjeQ3CB01G945QwQ097Mr7u0Lnxk20x+shNIJFyOdaQRvCkEvp6xat9gs3IDF2cqPV&#10;gdexkWbUE4vbXsZRlEqrO2KHVg/41mJ9PlysgtPX9JRspuozHLP9Kn3VXVa5m1KPD/P7lsfLFkTA&#10;Ofx9wG8Hzg8lB6vchYwXvYJ0GcVMVRDHSQKCGdk6zkBUfElXCciykP+LlD8AAAD//wMAUEsBAi0A&#10;FAAGAAgAAAAhALaDOJL+AAAA4QEAABMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFtDb250ZW50X1R5cGVzXS54&#10;bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAOP0h/9YAAACUAQAACwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAvAQAAX3JlbHMvLnJl&#10;bHNQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAcWtoUiECAAAdBAAADgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAuAgAAZHJzL2Uyb0Rv&#10;Yy54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAiK7BRuMAAAAQAQAADwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB7BAAAZHJzL2Rv&#10;d25yZXYueG1sUEsFBgAAAAAEAAQA8wAAAIsFAAAAAA==&#10;" stroked="f">
        <v:textbox>
          <w:txbxContent>
            <w:p w14:paraId="467DC1DB" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="00200C54" w:rsidRDefault="00200C54" w:rsidP="00200C54">
              <w:pPr>
                <w:jc w:val="center"/>
              </w:pPr>
              <w:r>
                <w:t>tLSTM</w:t>
              </w:r>
            </w:p>
          </w:txbxContent>
        </v:textbox>
      </v:shape>
    </w:pict>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:pict w14:anchorId="0D832600">
      <v:line id="Straight Connector 8" o:spid="_x0000_s1028" style="position:absolute;left:0;text-align:left;flip:y;z-index:2;visibility:visible;mso-width-relative:margin;mso-height-relative:margin" from="205.4pt,44.35pt" to="249.05pt,45.55pt" o:gfxdata="UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbJSRQU7DMBBF&#10;90jcwfIWJU67QAgl6YK0S0CoHGBkTxKLZGx5TGhvj5O2G0SRWNoz/78nu9wcxkFMGNg6quQqL6RA&#10;0s5Y6ir5vt9lD1JwBDIwOMJKHpHlpr69KfdHjyxSmriSfYz+USnWPY7AufNIadK6MEJMx9ApD/oD&#10;OlTrorhX2lFEilmcO2RdNtjC5xDF9pCuTyYBB5bi6bQ4syoJ3g9WQ0ymaiLzg5KdCXlKLjvcW893&#10;SUOqXwnz5DrgnHtJTxOsQfEKIT7DmDSUCaxw7Rqn8787ZsmRM9e2VmPeBN4uqYvTtW7jvijg9N/y&#10;JsXecLq0q+WD6m8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJl&#10;bHOkkMFqwzAMhu+DvYPRfXGawxijTi+j0GvpHsDYimMaW0Yy2fr2M4PBMnrbUb/Q94l/f/hMi1qR&#10;JVI2sOt6UJgd+ZiDgffL8ekFlFSbvV0oo4EbChzGx4f9GRdb25HMsYhqlCwG5lrLq9biZkxWOiqY&#10;22YiTra2kYMu1l1tQD30/bPm3wwYN0x18gb45AdQl1tp5j/sFB2T0FQ7R0nTNEV3j6o9feQzro1i&#10;OWA14Fm+Q8a1a8+Bvu/d/dMb2JY5uiPbhG/ktn4cqGU/er3pcvwCAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAA&#10;IQBOa9I08gEAAMcDAAAOAAAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWysU02P0zAQvSPxHyzfadqyQUvUdA+tlssK&#10;KrVwn3XsxMJf8pim+feM3dIWuCFysGzPvJeZN8+rp5M17Cgjau9avpjNOZNO+E67vuVfD8/vHjnD&#10;BK4D451s+SSRP63fvlmNoZFLP3jTyciIxGEzhpYPKYWmqlAM0gLOfJCOgspHC4mOsa+6CCOxW1Mt&#10;5/MP1ehjF6IXEpFut+cgXxd+paRIX5RCmZhpOdWWyhrL+prXar2Cpo8QBi0uZcA/VGFBO/rplWoL&#10;CdiPqP+islpEj16lmfC28kppIUsP1M1i/kc3+wGCLL2QOBiuMuH/oxWfj7vIdNdyGpQDSyPapwi6&#10;HxLbeOdIQB/ZY9ZpDNhQ+sbtYu5UnNw+vHjxHZnzmwFcL0u9hykQySIjqt8g+YDhDD6paJkyOnzL&#10;qZmOpGCnMpfpOhd5SkzQZV0/vK9rzgSFFvXyoYytgiazZGyImD5Jb1netNxol1WDBo4vmHIdt5R8&#10;7fyzNqZM3jg2EufHeU3mEEAGVAYSbW0gSdD1nIHpydkixUKJ3uguwzMRTrgxkR2BzEWe7Px4oJI5&#10;M4CJAtRH+YoUlH0PzZVuAYczuKPd2YpWJ3oPRlsayD3YuPxDWRx9aeqmZ969+m7axV+ik1tK2xdn&#10;Zzven8tobu9v/RMAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAMrmE8fjAAAADgEAAA8AAABkcnMvZG93bnJl&#10;di54bWxMj8FOwzAQRO9I/IO1SNyoY1TaJI1TIapyRLRw4ebGJomw15HtNIGvZzmVy0qj3Z15U21n&#10;Z9nZhNh7lCAWGTCDjdc9thLe3/Z3ObCYFGplPRoJ3ybCtr6+qlSp/YQHcz6mlpEJxlJJ6FIaSs5j&#10;0xmn4sIPBmn36YNTiWRouQ5qInNn+X2WrbhTPVJCpwbz1Jnm6zg6CZN9Xj3oYjh87HkQ69efUePu&#10;Rcrbm3m3ofG4AZbMnC4f8NeB+KEmsJMfUUdmJSxFRvxJQp6vgdHBssgFsJOEQgjgdcX/16h/AQAA&#10;//8DAFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABbQ29udGVu&#10;dF9UeXBlc10ueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhADj9If/WAAAAlAEAAAsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALwEA&#10;AF9yZWxzLy5yZWxzUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAE5r0jTyAQAAxwMAAA4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALgIA&#10;AGRycy9lMm9Eb2MueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAMrmE8fjAAAADgEAAA8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA&#10;TAQAAGRycy9kb3ducmV2LnhtbFBLBQYAAAAABAAEAPMAAABcBQAAAAA=&#10;" strokecolor="windowText" strokeweight="1.5pt">
        <v:stroke dashstyle="dash" joinstyle="miter"/>
      </v:line>
    </w:pict>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:pict w14:anchorId="7B559002">
      <v:line id="Straight Connector 9" o:spid="_x0000_s1027" style="position:absolute;left:0;text-align:left;z-index:3;visibility:visible;mso-width-relative:margin;mso-height-relative:margin" from="203.6pt,47.3pt" to="249.65pt,114pt" o:gfxdata="UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbJSRQU7DMBBF&#10;90jcwfIWJU67QAgl6YK0S0CoHGBkTxKLZGx5TGhvj5O2G0SRWNoz/78nu9wcxkFMGNg6quQqL6RA&#10;0s5Y6ir5vt9lD1JwBDIwOMJKHpHlpr69KfdHjyxSmriSfYz+USnWPY7AufNIadK6MEJMx9ApD/oD&#10;OlTrorhX2lFEilmcO2RdNtjC5xDF9pCuTyYBB5bi6bQ4syoJ3g9WQ0ymaiLzg5KdCXlKLjvcW893&#10;SUOqXwnz5DrgnHtJTxOsQfEKIT7DmDSUCaxw7Rqn8787ZsmRM9e2VmPeBN4uqYvTtW7jvijg9N/y&#10;JsXecLq0q+WD6m8AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQA4/SH/1gAAAJQBAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJl&#10;bHOkkMFqwzAMhu+DvYPRfXGawxijTi+j0GvpHsDYimMaW0Yy2fr2M4PBMnrbUb/Q94l/f/hMi1qR&#10;JVI2sOt6UJgd+ZiDgffL8ekFlFSbvV0oo4EbChzGx4f9GRdb25HMsYhqlCwG5lrLq9biZkxWOiqY&#10;22YiTra2kYMu1l1tQD30/bPm3wwYN0x18gb45AdQl1tp5j/sFB2T0FQ7R0nTNEV3j6o9feQzro1i&#10;OWA14Fm+Q8a1a8+Bvu/d/dMb2JY5uiPbhG/ktn4cqGU/er3pcvwCAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAA&#10;IQDiYn9F7wEAAL4DAAAOAAAAZHJzL2Uyb0RvYy54bWysU02P0zAQvSPxHyzfadJlC23UdA+tlssK&#10;KrX8gFnHSSz8JY9pkn/P2P3YAjdEDtbY43me9+Zl/TQazU4yoHK25vNZyZm0wjXKdjX/fnz+sOQM&#10;I9gGtLOy5pNE/rR5/249+Eo+uN7pRgZGIBarwde8j9FXRYGilwZw5ry0lGxdMBBpG7qiCTAQutHF&#10;Q1l+KgYXGh+ckIh0ujsn+Sbjt60U8VvbooxM15x6i3kNeX1Na7FZQ9UF8L0SlzbgH7owoCw9eoPa&#10;QQT2M6i/oIwSwaFr40w4U7i2VUJmDsRmXv7B5tCDl5kLiYP+JhP+P1jx9bQPTDU1X3FmwdCIDjGA&#10;6vrIts5aEtAFtko6DR4rur61+5CYitEe/IsTP5BZt+3BdjL3e5w8gcxTRfFbSdqgPxePbTAJhARg&#10;Y57GdJuGHCMTdLhYPi4/LjgTlFo+fi5XeVoFVNdiHzB+kc6wFNRcK5vEggpOLxjT81Bdr6Rj656V&#10;1nng2rKBelyVC/KEAPJdqyFSaDwpgbbjDHRHhhYxZEh0WjWpPAHhhFsd2AnIU2TFxg1H6pkzDRgp&#10;QUTylxWg2/elqZ8dYH8ubig6O9CoSL+BVoao3hdrmx6U2cgXUm8ypujVNdM+XLUmk2TaF0MnF97v&#10;80TefrvNLwAAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAMoUjjTgAAAADwEAAA8AAABkcnMvZG93bnJldi54&#10;bWxMT0tOwzAQ3SNxB2sqsaN2TVSaNE6FIFRiSekBpvGQRI3tKHY+vT1mBZuRnuZ988NiOjbR4Ftn&#10;FWzWAhjZyunW1grOX++PO2A+oNXYOUsKbuThUNzf5ZhpN9tPmk6hZtHE+gwVNCH0Gee+asigX7ue&#10;bPx9u8FgiHCouR5wjuam41KILTfY2pjQYE+vDVXX02gUmCo9jjSV5VGeb3zm/fWjwVKph9Xyto/n&#10;ZQ8s0BL+FPC7IfaHIha7uNFqzzoFiXiWkaogTbbAIiFJ0ydgFwVS7gTwIuf/dxQ/AAAA//8DAFBL&#10;AQItABQABgAIAAAAIQC2gziS/gAAAOEBAAATAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABbQ29udGVudF9UeXBl&#10;c10ueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhADj9If/WAAAAlAEAAAsAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALwEAAF9yZWxz&#10;Ly5yZWxzUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAOJif0XvAQAAvgMAAA4AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALgIAAGRycy9l&#10;Mm9Eb2MueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAMoUjjTgAAAADwEAAA8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAASQQAAGRy&#10;cy9kb3ducmV2LnhtbFBLBQYAAAAABAAEAPMAAABWBQAAAAA=&#10;" strokecolor="windowText" strokeweight="1.5pt">
        <v:stroke dashstyle="dash" joinstyle="miter"/>
      </v:line>
    </w:pict>
  </w:r>
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:pict w14:anchorId="1C829DE8">
      <v:shapetype id="_x0000_t75" coordsize="21600,21600" o:spt="75" o:preferrelative="t" path="m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe" filled="f" stroked="f">
        <v:stroke joinstyle="miter"/>
        <v:formulas>
          <v:f eqn="if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum @0 1 0"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum 0 0 @1"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @2 1 2"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelWidth"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @3 21600 pixelHeight"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum @0 0 1"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @6 1 2"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelWidth"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum @8 21600 0"/>
          <v:f eqn="prod @7 21600 pixelHeight"/>
          <v:f eqn="sum @10 21600 0"/>
        </v:formulas>
        <v:path o:extrusionok="f" gradientshapeok="t" o:connecttype="rect"/>
        <o:lock v:ext="edit" aspectratio="t"/>
      </v:shapetype>
      <v:shape id="Picture 6" o:spid="_x0000_s1026" type="#_x0000_t75" style="position:absolute;left:0;text-align:left;margin-left:247.8pt;margin-top:10pt;width:186pt;height:112.15pt;z-index:-1;visibility:visible" wrapcoords="17332 576 17332 2880 3571 3024 1742 3312 1742 5184 348 5328 348 6192 1742 7488 1742 9792 871 12096 871 12816 1481 14400 1742 16704 261 16848 261 18000 2439 19008 2613 21456 3135 21456 5661 21312 18726 19440 19945 19008 21426 17712 21339 16704 19510 14400 19510 7488 20816 7200 20816 5472 19510 4752 18639 3456 17855 2880 18639 2016 18639 864 17768 576 17332 576">
        <v:imagedata r:id="rId8" o:title=""/>
        <w10:wrap type="tight"/>
      </v:shape>
    </w:pict>
  </w:r>
  <w:r w:rsidR="00524183">
    <w:rPr>
      <w:noProof/>
      <w:lang w:val="en-US"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:pict w14:anchorId="63A496C5">
      <v:shape id="Picture 5" o:spid="_x0000_i1025" type="#_x0000_t75" style="width:191.7pt;height:128.1pt;visibility:visible">
        <v:imagedata r:id="rId9" o:title=""/>
      </v:shape>
    </w:pict>
  </w:r>
</w:p>
```

The images are in the docx file, but do not show up in document.inline_shapes (python-docx), hence I have no idea how to continue.. any help appreciated :)

Comment: You can extract the name of the image by id element  **id="Picture 5"** After that use this code to add image in the docx `from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

p = document.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
r.add_text('Good Morning every body,This is my ')
r.add_picture('/tmp/foo.jpg')
r.add_text(' do you like it?')

document.save('demo.docx')`

Answer (score 1):

This may not be a direct answer to your question, but it is worth considering.

If you have control over `docA`, have you considered the use of a docx template? In my problem I needed to generate reports from a template, so I had to copy information from python variables into a document, to generate a report. I found this project library which does replacement: https://github.com/elapouya/python-docx-template

Finally, you can replace the content from your variables like this:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

doc = DocxTemplate("my_word_template.docx")
context = { 'company_name' : "World company" }
doc.render(context)
doc.save("generated_doc.docx")
```

I have not checked but I believe this does preserve formatting. Here is an example of what my template looked like before replacing variables:

[image: example]

Comment: Hi :) Yes I have tried using python-docx-template, but the problem is with the images within the docx. I have done everything (including image file extraction) but I just need to know the location of the image within the docx, so that I can know where to slot the image into DocB (i.e. The location of {{company_logo_img}}). Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Check this code you can identify the location of an image after a specific text:

```
tags = []
for t in document.element.getiterator():
    if t.tag in ['{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}r','{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}t','{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}drawing']:
        if t.tag == '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}drawing':
            print('Picture Found')
        else:
            print(t.text)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your help in the previous qn :) I ran your code but I am unable to find images. However, I managed to isolate paragraphs that contain images (albeit in a very primitive way), which is a start.. I have edited my qn above. Now I have to find a way to copy the img to the other doc..

Answer (score 1):

Check this code. You can extract image position between two texts and image name by:

```
tags = []
text = []
for t in doc.element.getiterator():
    if t.tag in ['{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}r', '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}t','{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture}cNvPr','{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}drawing']:
        if t.tag == '{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture}cNvPr':
            print('Picture Found: ',t.attrib['name'])
            tags.append('Picture')
            text.append(t.attrib['name'])
        elif t.text:
            tags.append('text')
            text.append(t.text)
```

You can check previous and next text from text list and their tag from the tag list.

If you have extracted the image location and image name then you can add the image in your docx file by this code

```
from docx import Document
document = Document()

p = document.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
r.add_text('Good Morning every body,This is my ')
r.add_picture('/tmp/foo.jpg')
r.add_text(' do you like it?')

document.save('demo.docx')
```

You can access the image by unzipping your docx file. when you will unzip you will get different folders. You can access all the images in the file from `word/media` folder

Check this link for unzipping a docx file
https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-extract-data-from-ms-word-documents-using-python-ed3fbb48c122

Comment: Hello there again :) So sorry.. to clarify, the problem might be that the docx file does not classify the images as inline_shapes or something. The output of your code is [] for tags, which is not your fault (I have a feeling that it has something to do with the tags). I will try different tags and see which one gives a hit. I have edited the qn to include the XML data from the Paragraph obj containing the images.